# Is there a Java equivalent or custom method for 'string.Insert()' in C#

Tags: java, string, insert, equivalent

I am trying to port some code from C# and I have come across

```
string.Insert(int startIndex, string value)
```

and there doesn't seem to be an obvious Java equivalent. Could anyone please help me with this issue and what I can do to solve it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does string.insert() do in c#?

Comment: it returns a new string in which a specified string is inserted at a specified index position in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
str = str.substring(0, startIndex) + value + str.substring(startIndex)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using StringBuilder:

```
String string = "test";
String string2 = new StringBuilder(string).insert(index, value).toString();
```

Comment: The use of `StringBuilder` is indeed preferred in most cases over String concatenation, because it is much more efficient. The class `StringBuffer` has very similar behavior, but is sort of deprecated since Java 1.5

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent might be

```
String.format("Original %s string", "thing to insert");
```

It doesn't specify the actual index but rather uses a format string. Which is nicer in some circumstances. Otherwise you have to use `String.substring()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use String concat or String Buffer

Here is an example using **String Buffer**

```
   StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer("I am right now."); 
  // Then, use the insert method, that is: 
    s1.insert(3, "busy");
```

**OP:** `I am busy right now.`

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way but you can convert string into Stringbuffer and then call its insert method.

```
String x="12345";
StringBuffer b=new StringBuffer(x);
b.insert(5, "hi");
System.out.println(b);
```

**output**

```
12345hi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and do a [ReplaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with a regex, it's a bit clanky but it does the job:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String original = "abcdefg";
    int position = 3;
    String inserted = "123";

    String newString = original.replaceFirst("^(.{" + position + "})", "$1" + inserted);

    System.out.println(newString); // abc123defg
}
```